# Как решить задачу без использования itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, перебор

[Наткнулся на задачку с перебором](https://stepik.org/lesson/193223/step/11?unit=192050), которую решил через [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), но **хотелось бы увидеть варианты решения, желательно, без использования библиотек**.

#### Задача:

> Имеется набор данных, состоящий из троек положительных целых чисел.
> Необходимо **выбрать из каждой тройки ровно одно число так, чтобы
> сумма всех выбранных чисел была чётной и минимально возможной**. Если
> получить требуемую сумму невозможно, в качестве ответа нужно выдать 0.
>
> На вход программе в первой строке подаётся количество троек чисел N (1
> < N < 100 000). Каждая из следующих N строк содержит три натуральных
> числа, не превышающих 10 000.

#### Входные данные:

> **Sample Input 1:**
>
> ```
> 5
> 2 3 2
> 2 3 3
> 2 2 1
> 3 3 5
> 1 1 1
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 1:**
>
> ```
> 10
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Sample Input 2:**
>
> ```
> 10
> 2 3 2
> 2 3 3
> 2 2 1
> 3 3 5
> 1 1 1
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 11 23 56
> 23 13 10
> 45 76 89
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 2:**
>
> ```
> 80
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Sample Input 3:**
>
> ```
> 10
> 2 3 2
> 2 3 3
> 2 2 1
> 3 3 5
> 1 1 1
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 11 23 56
> 23 13 9
> 44 76 89
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 3:**
>
> ```
> 78
> ```

### Моё решение:

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]

min_number = 1_000_000
for items in itertools.product(*matrix):
    sum_number = sum(items)
    if sum_number % 2 == 0:
        min_number = min(min_number, sum_number)
print(min_number)
```

---

Понимая что удовольствия переписывать входные данные нет, привожу их в коде (**Sample Input 2**):

```
matrix = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in """
2 3 2
2 3 3
2 2 1
3 3 5
1 1 1
1 2 3
4 5 6
11 23 56
23 13 10
45 76 89
""".strip().splitlines()]
n = len(matrix)
```

Comment: Вам необходимо решение другой асимптотической сложности? Или просто переписать функцию `product`?

Comment: @nomnoms12, пытался решить через вложенные циклы и мозг сломал, пытаясь представить алгоритм :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, у меня получилось почти то же самое, что предложил Эникейщик. Правда я хранил не разницу, а само второе минимальное число.

Алгоритм таков:
Считается сумма минимальных чисел из каждой тройки.
Параллельно сохраняется второе минимальное число при условии что оно: имеет нечётную разницу с первым минимальным (чётным сумму не поправишь) и, в принципе, минимальное из всех найденных. Также сохраняется первое минимальное число (чтобы его потом выкинуть из суммы).
Если в конце концов сумма нечётная, то из неё вычитается сохранённое число и прибавляется второе минимальное. *(Ну да, здесь, в принципе, можно сразу хранить просто разницу между этими числами.)*

```
summ = 0
min2 = (float('inf'), None)

for _ in range(int(input())):
    numb1, numb2, numb3 = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    summ += numb1
    if   numb2-numb1 & 1 and numb2 < min2[0]: min2 = (numb2, numb1)
    elif numb3-numb1 & 1 and numb3 < min2[0]: min2 = (numb3, numb1)

if summ & 1:
    summ += min2[0] - min2[1] if min2[1] != None else -summ

print(summ)
```

Comment: Проверил, код прошел проверку тестовой системы (+1). А почему после цикла проверяем сумму на четность и эти дополнительные действия? Непонятно еще почему numb2 и numb3 должны быть четными

Comment: @gil9red Операция `& 1` - это проверка на нечётность (младший бит числа = 1) _(привычка с ассемблерных языков что битовые операции работают быстрее :) )_. Эквивалентно `% 2`. Дополнительные действия в случае нечётной суммы: вычитаем первое минимальное число сохранённого ряда и прибавляем второе минимальное. Если таких чисел не было, то обнуляем сумму согласно условию задачи.

Comment: @gil9red Хотя... Знаете, вы правы насчёт проверки на нечётность самих чисел. Надо проверять на нечётность разницу. Поправил код. Странно, что тестовая система не подсовывает такие тесты. Например, `1\n  1 2 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Как такой алгоритм:

1. Сложить минимальные числа из каждой тройки. Если сумма четная - профит.

Если нет:

2. В каждой тройке найти разницу между минимальным и средним (по величине, а не расположению) числом.
3. К нечетной сумме прибавить минимальную нечетную разницу.

Comment: Выглядит правдоподобно, а кодом? :)

Comment: это тока попозже :)

Comment: Считать придётся разницу между минимальным и обоими оставшимися. (1 1 1) (2 4 7) (2 4 6) - без семёрки не обойтись

Comment: @MBo хаха, отличный кейс! Точно, может оказаться и так, что там не окажется нечетных разниц. Тогда, пожалуй, считать сразу обе разницы и сохранять нечетную. Ну или 0, если такой нет.